# Mac executable not working when downloaded online

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyinstaller

I have made a small (8 MB) program into a MAC executable (.app?)

It works great if I share it using a thumbstick, but if I try to upload it to google drive and then download it it doesn't work. By this I mean It first tells me that It is an unidentified source (this seems reasonable)

[image]

But then if I click "open"

It opens as a text file with junk data:

[image]

If I try to force it to open on the terminal, how the other program opens, it just shows the heartbeat thing that MACs do when opening a file, but never opens anything.

It is certifiably the same exact file. Same size, same name, same goobldygoop if I open both of them as text files instead of executables.

I am really confused, the only thing I can think of is the "signature" that apple uses is lost when it is compressed into a zip, but I'm probably totally off base.

The code uses python 3.7, pyinstaller, pynput, and selenium.
I am using MAC OS Catalina to write and make into an EXE, then another Catalina to try to run the program.

EDIT: Clarify what doesn't work means

Please help.

Comment: You may need to clarify what you mean by "doesn't work". Do you get an error message? Is that message something specific to your program or specific to Mac (e.g. file permissions)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, simply zip the file from my mac and send it that way!
Yay!